# i am getting an error " Undefined property: stdClass::$payment_link " while processing payment from cashfree

Tags: laravel

hello i am working on a website where i have to accept some payments i am using Cashfree payment gateway, i saw multiple tutorials but i am stuck i am always getting this same error " Undefined property: stdClass::$payment_link "

Code for my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
     {
          $validated = $request->validate([
               'name' => 'required|min:3',
               'email' => 'required',
               'mobile' => 'required',
               'amount' => 'required'
          ]);
               
          $url = "https://api.cashfree.com/pg";

          $headers = array(
               "Content-Type: application/json",
               "x-api-version: 2022-01-01",
               "x-client-id: ".env('CASHFREE_API_KEY'),
               "x-client-secret: ".env('CASHFREE_API_SECRET')
          );

          $data = json_encode([
               'order_id' =>  'order_'.rand(1111111111,9999999999),
               'order_amount' => $validated['amount'],
               "order_currency" => "INR",
               "customer_details" => [
                    "customer_id" => 'customer_'.rand(111111111,999999999),
                    "customer_name" => $validated['name'],
                    "customer_email" => $validated['email'],
                    "customer_phone" => $validated['mobile'],
               ],
               "order_meta" => [
                    "return_url" => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cashfree/payments/success/?order_id={order_id}&order_token={order_token}'
               ]
          ]);

          $curl = curl_init($url);

          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

          $resp = curl_exec($curl);

          curl_close($curl);

          return redirect()->to(json_decode($resp)->payment_link);
     }
```

my blade file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Laravel 9 Cashfree Payment Gateway Integration Tutorial</title>
     <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container mt-3">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
               <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <div class="card text-dark bg-light mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header text-center">
                         <h3 class="card-title " style="display: inline-block;">Create New Payment - Webappfix</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                         <form action="{{ route('store') }}" method="POST" name="laravel9-cashfree-integration">
                              @csrf
                              <div class="form-floating py-2">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="name">
                              <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-floating py-2">
                              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="email">
                              <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-floating py-2">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="mobile" value="{{ old('mobile') }}" placeholder="mobile">
                              <label for="mobile">Mobile Number</label>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-floating py-2">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount" id="amount" value="{{ old('amount') }}" placeholder="amount">
                              <label for="amount">Amount</label>
                              </div>
                              <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit">Place Order</button>
                         </form>
                         @if ($errors->any())
                         <div class="alert alert-danger text-start" role="alert">
                              <strong>Opps!</strong> Something went wrong<br>
                              <ul>
                              @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                   <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                              @endforeach
                              </ul>
                         </div>
                         @endif
                    </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my routes

```
Route::get('cashfree/payments/create', [CashfreePaymentController::class, 'create'])->name('callback');
Route::post('cashfree/payments/store', [CashfreePaymentController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
Route::any('cashfree/payments/success', [CashfreePaymentController::class, 'success'])->name('success');
```

my api keys
CASHFREE_API_KEY=6508266e4e10074c53f7c91dea628056
CASHFREE_API_SECRET=cfsk_ma_prod_8da5f935461aaedc1a97a236c4d4a307_e03b6716

i also tried changing the api version date to 2023-08-01, but didn't work

Any help is much appreaceated

Comment: Laravel has an http client that can be used to simplify requests to external apis, might help in debugging your issues. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client

Comment: i already tried that but it didn't work

Comment: Tbh that was more a bit of advice to clean up your code rather then a solution to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

we do not support sending payment_link in the newer versions of API anymore in the response.
Use the latest version "2023-08-01" and then follow this documentation to open the checkout page -> https://docs.cashfree.com/docs/open-checkoutx

Comment: can you help me with 2022 version actually i am new to laravel and php so detailed help will be much appreciated

Comment: Whatever you have done above, do the same thing but change the x-api-version to 2023-08-01 and in the response check for "payment_session_id" and then follow the docs -> https://docs.cashfree.com/docs/open-checkoutx (This is javascript)

Comment: i changed the api version to 2023-08-01 and changed           return redirect()->to(json_decode($resp)->payment_link);
 to           return redirect()->to(json_decode($resp)->payment_session_id); but i got the same error the only change in the error heading now it is payment_session_id

Comment: Not sure what this redirect() does. But payment_session_id does not load any payment page. Please follow the above link to open the payment page